# How can I program iOS AutoLayout constraints using Greater Than or Equal without making the layout ambiguous?

Tags: c#, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, autolayout

I am writing an iOS app using MonoTouch where I want to programmatically define all of my UIViews and the AutoLayout constraints that define their layout. I am currently trying to create a Table-like collection of views (rows & columns, not a UITableView) and I am able to use AutoLayout constraints to adjust column and row "borders" or markers. It looks fine when I run the app, but I keep getting an ambiguous layout for the table (using the HasAmbiguousLayout field). I have distilled it down to the fact that my border markers use GreaterThanOrEqual (GTE) constraints rather than Equal, which is required since I want to make sure my rows and columns fit an arbitrary number of views.

My understanding was than I can use GTE type constraints and the AutoLayout system will attempt to minimize the value so that it is still GTE (vice-versa for LTE constraints). For example, I would expect that I can place a view's left egde GTE the right edges of 2 other views, so that the layout solver will determine the minimum value for the left edge such that it is still satisfying GTE the right edges of the other views.

I created a simple example and I am not sure why I get an ambiguous layout. I created a single-view project in MonoTouch and programmatically add a UIView box that serves as my container (which in more complex examples contains multiple rows and columns of views). I then add only 1 subview to the box view, a UILabel called myLabel. I add constraints to place the label within the box, place the box within the parent View, and set the box's right and bottom edges (this is the key part):

```
public partial class AutoLayoutTestViewController : UIViewController
{
    public AutoLayoutTestViewController () : base ("AutoLayoutTestViewController", null)
    {
        UIView box = new UIView ();
        box.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green;
        box.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        View.AddSubview (box);
        View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (box, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 50f));
        View.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (box, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, View, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1.0f, 0f));

        UILabel myLabel = new UILabel ();
        myLabel.Text = "My Label";
        myLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
        myLabel.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
        box.AddSubview (myLabel);
        box.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (myLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, box, NSLayoutAttribute.Top, 1.0f, 10f));
        box.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (myLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, NSLayoutRelation.Equal, box, NSLayoutAttribute.Left, 1.0f, 10f));
        // IMPORTANT CONSTRAINTS
        box.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (box, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, myLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, 1.0f, 10f));
        box.AddConstraint (NSLayoutConstraint.Create (box, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, NSLayoutRelation.GreaterThanOrEqual, myLabel, NSLayoutAttribute.Right, 1.0f, 10f));
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning ()
    {
        // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

        // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
    }

    public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews ();
        foreach (UIView v in View.Subviews) {
            if (v.HasAmbiguousLayout) {
                Console.WriteLine ("WARNING: View {0} has ambiguous layout!", v);
            }
        }
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }
}
```

The following screenshot shows that the box and label appear as I want, but when the view controller finishes laying out the subviews, I get the message that my box has ambiguous layout. If I change the "important constraints" for the box's right and bottom edges to be Equal to rather than GreaterThanOrEqual then the layout is no longer ambiguous. Again, it is important that I be able to specify my constraints as GTE because I am setting my borders with respect to an arbitrary number of views in rows and columns, so as I add new views to the table, I make sure that my right edge is constrained to be GTE all of the views and similarly for the bottom edge. I cannot use strictly equal to in my app because I do not know which subview in the table will be the right-most or bottom-most view; this is the reason for having GTE constraints.

[image: AutoLayout test]

My questions are: why can't I use GTE constraints here for my box view without getting an ambiguous layout? If this simple example does not work, how then do you use GTE constraints at all (they would all be ambiguous, otherwise you would specify them as Equal in the first place)?

Thanks for any help,

Cam

Comment: Generally I do the same kind of thing, use GTE to insure something is limited in one dimension, but then add another constraint with a lower priority that attempts to do something else, like center a view within another view. You have to get creative. The best way I've found is using pencil and paper, sketch an example out, and try to construct where I need what constraints. Good luck!

Comment: It's not clear why you need GTE constraints. As you add new boxes, do you want the existing ones to get closer together? What borders are you talking about with "I am setting my borders with respect to an arbitrary number of views"? Also, is there a reason you're not using a UICollectionView to do this?

Comment: @rdelmar, think of it this way, I am building a simple table containing various views of different sizes and shapes but the left and right edges of each column should be aligned as should the top and bottom edges of each row. So without knowing what each column contains, I want the next column to start at a point GTE each UIView in the preceding column. It's just aligning everything. My example is just illustrating my issue with the AutoLayout constraint, don't mind that I am only adding 1 view to the box container (it is a 1x1 table). Does that clarify?

Comment: @rdelmar, I found the UICollectionView to be better suited to grid layouts of same-sized views, and it seemed to require a bit more setup than what I ultimately implemented, which works very well except for the fact that it supposedly is ambiguous. My question really boils down to how to properly use GTE constraints while making the layout unambiguous. If I apply multiple GTE constraints on a view's edge, it does work and it sets the edge to be the **smallest** value st it still satisfies all GTE constraints. That is what I'm trying to do here, but wondering why it says it is ambiguous.

Comment: @DavidH, you're right, I added lower priority constraints to try to push both edges to a minimum (right edge == left edge and bottom edge == top edge with priority 500). I am wondering if this is always necessary when using inequality constraints? It seems a little redundant since the system already solves the constraints to find the smallest value GTE (or largest value LTE). I will use this approach from now on though, just to avoid ambiguity warnings. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I do the same kind of thing, use GTE to insure something is limited in one dimension, but then add another constraint with a lower priority that attempts to do something else, like center a view within another view. You have to get creative. The best way I've found is using pencil and paper, sketch an example out, and try to construct where I need what constraints.

I do not believe the system can equally allocate inequalities - if you have one on the left edge and one on the right edge, what should it do? I use inequalities to insure that some maximum is never exceeded, then lower priority ones to try and achieve some goal (i.e. centering).